# OpenCV Line-Mod problems with Images

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to use line-mod (in special line-2d) in opencv 2.4 to compare images. At the moment I try to change the test-implementation linemod.cpp to use an input images instead of the camera, but without any success.

I tried to load an image via imread('...', CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); and pushed that in the sources vector but got a 'OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (response_map.rows % T == 0) in linearize' error.

If I load a CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE image the run stops at detector->match with the error 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11310f000)'.

I don't understand what makes the difference between images coming from a VideoCapturer and from imread...

Is there anyone out there that may help me? I'm totally lost ... again ;-)

(For example sample code for matching two objects from images with linemod would be absolutely great!)

I use opencv 2.4 with xcode on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late for an answer, but I am also interested in the algorithm

In the OpenCV Minutes 2012-06-26 ( http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/2012 ) you can read:

> Will work with Stefan Hinterstoisser for final version of LINEMOD by September

So if you did not already solve it, you may want to wait.

Comment: Hey BeLioN big thank's for your answer! Since I did not solve the problem I'll just wait ;-)